# PHP retrieve json values without loop through the whole json object

Tags: php, json

I'm a newbie in the PHP area, so please bear with my question.

Basically I have/will have a pretty big json file, and I need to query the file to get a single entry based on the key provided. An example would be as follow:

```
{
"key1" : {value1},
"key2" : {value2},
...,
"keyn" : {valuen}
}
```

I will need to retrieve only one value at any one request, and hope to get a better performance.

The basic way to deal with this sort of handling in PHP from my search is to use `json_decode()` and then `foreach`.

However, this approach seems like need to iterate through the whole file based on the order of the key and what the key I am looking for. So if I am looking for keyn, then essentially I have to read from top to bottom of the large file. (Yep, I can use some sort algorithm to get a better result)

But from my understanding, JSON is basically another form of HashMap, so given HashMap can `get` easily and fast, is there a similar way in PhP to get the best performance out of it?

Comment: Also, to measure performance relative to your existing code, we would need to see your existing code.

Comment: I don't have an existing code, so above speculation is only based on theory (which of course can be totally wrong). The thing I am curiously to know is if there is any sort of built-in function or library that will load a json string into a map, and after then the read from map will be definitely faster. I understand there will be overhead regarding the load, so that' why I need help from you guys who have more PhP experience.

Comment: if you're question is really "how to efficiently get a certain value from within a big data set" you should consider using a real database, with proper indexes defined. databases are used everywhere for this reason. json is a data interchange format, and efficient random access of data within it is not one of its strengths.

Comment: You are right about the target. However, due to the limitation of the application, I have to deal with this JSON formatted string, and parse it using PHP in real time to get certain value. Hence my question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, given the structure you provided you definitely don't need to loop through the entire object.

If you're looking for `keyn`, you would just do:

```
$obj = json_decode($input);
echo $obj->keyn;
```

Maybe I'm missing something obvious. If you want to prevent having to json_decode the entire object, your question makes a bit more sense though... but that's not what you're asking.

Comment: Yep, I think I would be happy to avoid json_decode, as I will just have a json-formatted string, and hoping to get a value of the given key in a best performance way without looping through the whole string.

Comment: You can't avoid `json_decode()`, I think that is the point you are missing here and everywhere else.

Comment: @Evert, I realized you are right, I can just simply call in the way of @obj->keyn to get the value I needed. I am wondering in terms of performance and efficiency, is this faster than the loop through? my feeling is $obj->keyn's internal implementation is still iterate through all arrays, but of course I may be wrong. Can you shaed some light here? Thanks

Comment: @RPM: you totally can given certain conditions. If keys are sorted alphabetically, and the values follow a certain pattern (for example only 1 nested object), you could jump halfway into the file and look for the next string matching `/},"[^"]+":/` with some confidence.

Comment: @YudongLi no it will be fast, it uses a hashmap internally. It's also quite clear to me now that you are optimizing something you don't even know that needs to be optimized. Measure first.

Comment: @Evert thanks, yes you are correct I've never deal with PHP before so had no idea how PHP is working here.

Answer (score 0):

From JSON.org

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, >record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array.
>   An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or >sequence.

You can't just interact with json without first using `json_decode()` to turn it into a usable object. But if you know the keys, after running `json_decode()` you can interact with it (because it's now an object). for example:

```
<?php
$string = '{"foo": "bar", "cool": "attr"}';
$result = json_decode($string);

// Result: object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["foo"]=> string(3) "bar" ["cool"]=> string(4) "attr" }
var_dump($result);

// Prints "bar"
echo $result->foo;

// Prints "attr"
echo $result->cool;
?>
```

In situations like this, `var_dump()` and `print_r()` are your friends.

Answer (score -1):

There really isn't any magical way to find the value without using any kind of loop

I haven't benchmarked this:

This is how I would approach the problem without having to finish the iterating over the whole tree if and when a match is foudn

```
$key = 'keyn'
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('path/to/your/file'), true);
$len = count($obj);
$match = false;

for($ii = 0; $ii < $len; $ii++){
   $curr = $obj[$ii];
   if($curr == $key) {
     $match = $curr;
   }
   break;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, though this is not really a solution I'm after. (Down-voter not from me, and not sure why either).

Comment: What kind of solution are you after, if I may.

Comment: I didn't see anything different being offered in your solution comparing to my description, that's why it's not a solution I'm after.

Comment: The OP is not interested in a foreach (the same functionality as your `for` solution) loop, even if you do offer a `break`.  For this reason, you should delete your answer.  Evert's answer is the way to go for this task.

Answer (score -2):

In PHP you can use function: file_get_contents to parse JSON file. You have to go through each and every key-value pairs.